# How to call or embedded VBS in Batch script

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, batch-processing

I would like batch to send email but since mailto command won't send email via outlook without me clicking send button.

I found this VBS Script online which sends email without human interactions.

I just need help call or if I can embedded VBS into BATCH file.

```
' Create email object
Set oolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set email = oolApp.CreateItem(0)
email.Recipients.Add("myemail@esomeemail.com")

' Create the body of the email
MailBody = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD W3 HTML//EN"">"
MailBody = MailBody & "<HTML>" & vbcrlf
MailBody = MailBody & "<HEAD><TITLE>No Invoices</TITLE></HEAD>"
MailBody = MailBody & "<BODY>" & vbcrlf
MailBody = MailBody & "<B>For Your Information</B>,<BR><BR>"
MailBody = MailBody & "No invoices were issued today.<BR><BR>"
MailBody = MailBody & "</BODY></HTML>"

' Send the Email
email.Subject = "No Invoices Issued"
email.HTMLBody = MailBody
email.Send
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074476/is-it-possible-to-embed-and-execute-vbscript-within-a-batch-file-without-using-a/26922679#26922679

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Now that I re-read your question, I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. Are you asking how to run a vbscript? Just save it to `filename.vbs` and execute it with

```
cscript filename.vbs
```

(or `cscript /nologo filename.vbs` if you want to avoid displaying Microsoft's cscript vanity spam).

---

On the other hand, if you want to incorporate this into a batch script, then there are lots of methods for echoing content from a batch script to an external file.  Most people just do something like

```
echo Set oolApp = CreateObject^("Outlook.Application"^)>> vbsfile
```

or similar, escaping with `^` as necessary.  However, you might find [this page of heredoc methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015163/) useful.  Here's an example using the [script I helped you make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364653) yesterday:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* (batch + jscript hybrid script init)

:: *** Batch script *****

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set recipient=myemail@esomeemail.com

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('wget "%~1" -O- -q 2^>NUL ^| findstr /i "last.*updated.*as.*of"') do (
    for /f "delims=" %%x in ('cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "%%I"') do (
        set /a "thirtyMinutes = 30 * 60 * 1000"
        if %%x GEQ !thirtyMinutes! (
            call :doEmail
        )
    )
    exit /b
)
exit /b

:doEmail
call :heredoc vbs >email.vbs && goto endvbs
' Create email object
Set oolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set email = oolApp.CreateItem(0)
email.Recipients.Add("!recipient!")

' Create the body of the email
MailBody = "<^!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD W3 HTML//EN"">"
MailBody = MailBody & "<HTML>" & vbcrlf
MailBody = MailBody & "<HEAD><TITLE>No Invoices</TITLE></HEAD>"
MailBody = MailBody & "<BODY>" & vbcrlf
MailBody = MailBody & "<B>For Your Information</B>,<BR><BR>"
MailBody = MailBody & "No invoices were issued today.<BR><BR>"
MailBody = MailBody & "</BODY></HTML>"

' Send the Email
email.Subject = "No Invoices Issued"
email.HTMLBody = MailBody
email.Send
:endvbs

cscript /nologo email.vbs
del email.vbs
goto :EOF

:: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15032476/1683264
:heredoc <uniqueIDX>
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set go=
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "%~f0"') do (
    set "line=%%A" && set "line=!line:*:=!"
    if defined go (if #!line:~1!==#!go::=! (goto :EOF) else echo(!line!)
    if "!line:~0,13!"=="call :heredoc" (
        for /f "tokens=3 delims=>^ " %%i in ("!line!") do (
            if #%%i==#%1 (
                for /f "tokens=2 delims=&" %%I in ("!line!") do (
                    for /f "tokens=2" %%x in ("%%I") do set "go=%%x"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
goto :EOF

:: *** JScript script *****/
var args = [];
for (var i=0; i<WScript.arguments.length; i++) { args.push(WScript.arguments(i)) }
var t = args.join(' ').replace(/^\s+|<[^>]+>|\s+$/g,'').replace(/\&nbsp;/g, ' ').split(' ');
var h = t[4].split(':')[0];
if (/pm/i.test(t[5])) h = h * 1 + 12;
var ds = t[6] + ' ' + t[7] + ', ' + new Date().getFullYear() + ' ' + h + ':' + t[4].split(':')[1];
var diff = new Date() - new Date(ds);
WScript.echo(diff);
```

I haven't tested this, but play around with it and see what you think.

Comment: Hi, Do you remember you help write http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364653/can-we-fetch-scrape-particular-data-from-html-site-into-batch-to-do-following/15368190#15368190 yesterday? so I am trying make that bat script send me email if via outlook if it has been 30 mins since last update. Thanks

Comment: Can you please tell me what is code below `goto :EOF` ? thanks

Comment: The JScript stuff is what scrapes the output of `wget`.  It strips out html tags, trims whitespace and converts `&nbsp;` to spaces to get to the `Last Updated as of 11:14 pm March 11th` text.  It then converts that bit of text to a Date object, subtracts it from the current Date, and echoes the number of milliseconds difference.  That difference is captured as `%%x` near the top of the script.  It's the same as it was [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15368190/1683264).

Comment: I meant to say, if that vbscript doesn't work for you, you could also use [blat](http://www.blat.net/) or [postie](http://www.infradig.com/command-line-email/index.html) or similar to send yourself an email.

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting it together, I will play with it to get it working. if not I'll just have batch script from yesterday call the first version of code you posted in this question(which sends email).

Comment: rojo, I was able to successfully able to get it working and send email as well. I just have one more thing I need your help with. Instead taking url from user with argument, can we hard code specific url ? instead of `%~1` may be like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364653/` thanks

Comment: I don't see why not.  Did you try it?  Just replace `%~1` with your static URL.  Leave it quoted.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know why but it didn't work when I tired it, but it works now :) Thanks. I would give you my 100 points if I can for all the work you helped me with.

Comment: rojo, I am stuck again, I am trying to set up a task scheduler for this batch script. it works fine if I run it manually but I get following error if this is ran from windows task scheduler `C:\bin\nf\email.vbs(2, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'Outlook.Application'` I am almost there plz help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26173/discussion-between-rojo-and-mowgli)